# How to parse a WSDL file to extract the contents of a particular node

Tags: java, xml, parsing, wsdl, wsdl2java

Here is a part of my wsdl file:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
- <wsdl:types>
- <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
- <s:element name="BinaryConversion">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Binary" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="BinaryConversionResponse">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BinaryConversionResult" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="Qos">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Availabilty_10" type="s:int" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="QosResponse">
  <s:complexType /> 
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="GetQosParameters">
  <s:complexType /> 
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="GetQosParametersResponse">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GetQosParametersResult" type="tns:QoSParameters" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:complexType name="QoSParameters">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Availability" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Accuracy" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Accessibility" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Latency" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Reliability" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
```

Now I want to extract the names Availability ,Accuracy,Latency etc.How do I do this.
I used Document Builder to parse but I am only able to extract wsdl:operations and not wsdl:types

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good Java/XML tutorial (one of many):

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html

Scroll down to the part where he talks about [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).  That's the syntax you need to fetch a subnode (e.g. "QoSParameters") and everything in it (e.g. "Availability", "Accuracy", etc).

Comment: Tanq paul, But i used NodeList elements = d.getElementsByTagName("s:complexTypes"); and it is not working,Is my syntax wrong,I was able to extract the service name,operations etc,But not the complexTypes